# Are there chatrooms for all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, chat

Are there chatrooms for all Stack Exchange sites? Does every site have an associated chat room?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The system automatically creates one room for each Stack Exchange site, and the chat system ensures that there is at least one unfrozen room for each site (unless a moderator manually freezes that last room). So... yes, there should be a chatroom for each site on the network, although with varying levels of activity.